# Looking for a unique number in an array using forLoop()

Tags: javascript

I am trying Javascript exercises and ran into a problem.
I have built a function to find if an array is consist of same numbers. 
return false if there's any unique number.

Here's what i came up with and I don't understand why it's not working.

```
function isUniform(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i-1] !== arr[i]); {
            return false;
        }
    }     
    return true;
}
```

why is this not working? what's the problem here? i am a complete noob!

Thanks gurus!

Comment: `if (arr[i-1] !== arr[i]); {` There should not be a semicolon there.

Comment: is the assumption that the array is sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first iteration will always `return false` (unless the first element of the array is undefined), because when `i` starts at 0,

```
if (arr[i-1] !== arr[i])
```

will always resolve to

```
if (false)
```

because `arr[i-1]` resolves to `arr[-1]`, which is almost certainly `undefined`. Arrays are zero-indexed, not `-1`-indexed. If you wanted to use a `for` loop, start at `i = 1` instead:

```js
function isUniform(arr){
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i-1] !== arr[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }     
  return true;
}
console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 1]));
console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 2]));
```

Or you might avoid loops and use `every` instead:

```js
function isUniform(arr){
  const [first] = arr;
  return arr.every(item => item === first);
}
console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 1]));
console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 2]));
```

Comment: I totally thought that the index will always start at 2 since forLoop has 'i++' at the end. What a precise explaination! Thank you! I can sleep now.